# How to pass parameters to scala view form java application controller?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to pass a string as a parameter  from the java application controller to scala view ,but i am getting error ,any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If you want that somebody would help you write once what did you try...

Answer (score 0):

That's easy:

controller:

```
return ok(yourView.render("Your string"));
```

view (declare param(s) in first line!):

```
@(param1: String)

<h1>@param1</h1>
```

Note, that Java doesn't allow for optional and/or named args, so you need always to pass the same number of arguments and in the same order as declared in the view

Comment: thanks, but instead of passing a single parameter i wanted to pass an array of string say "abc" ,where "abc" is an array of String,any idea?

Comment: so you can send ie: `Map<String, String>`

Comment: actually i am trying to send the array of string to the index view page, i am getting error if i try to send it

Comment: Attempting this results in the error `method render in class views.html.login cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your error is, it's difficult to troubleshoot, but I'm assuming that the error is just an issue with the implicit java collections to scala collections conversion.  Based on your comments in @biesior's question I'm not even sure what your data type is, I think it's a 2D string array, i.e. `String[][]  templateStrings` but you describe it working like a `Map<String, String[]> templateStrings`

If it is the first case, I think the equivalent scala collection would be Array[Array[String]]; if it's the second then Seq[String, Array[String]]. Try defining that in your template parameter list, then passing in your java collection to the `return ok(yourView.render(templateStrings));`, as per biesior's answer.